# Issue using jsoup to select tags within div

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsoup

I have a html file that contains content like:

```
<div class="title"><a href="../dorothy_perkins_true_blue_suedette/thing?id=130434603" title="Dorothy Perkins True blue suedette clutch bag">Dorothy Perkins True blue suedette clutch bag</a></div>
```

I want to extract the url in `href`. I have the following code:

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements products = doc.select("div.title a[href]");
            System.out.println("size: "+products.size());
```

The print shows, however, the size is 0. It cannot find any match. The url I'm using is `http://www.polyvore.com/bags/shop?category_id=35`. You can take a look at the source, I'm pretty sure the code above is right. That would be great if anybody can give some idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like the website does not want to be scraped, so you must change the User Agent, as per the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you use following code to connect.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.polyvore.com/bags/shop?category_id=35").get();
```

If you do `System.out.println(doc.html());`, it returns whole chunk of HTML source which is totally different from what we see through browsers like Mozilla and Chrome.

To solve this problem, you need to specify `userAgent` parameter in Jsoup connection as below.

```
    Document doc = null;
    Elements aEles = null;

    try {
        // doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.polyvore.com/bags/shop?category_id=35").get();

        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.polyvore.com/bags/shop?category_id=35")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();

        if (doc != null) {
            aEles = doc.select("div.title > a");

            if (aEles != null)
                System.out.println("size: " + aEles.size());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But can you further explain what userAgent and referrer are? I've never used them. Thanks.

Comment: A web server uses User Agent to serve different web pages to different browsers. For example, a website could send mobile pages to mobile browsers and modern pages to modern browsers. When a browser connects to a website, it includes a User-Agent field in its HTTP header so that the web server can identify the browser. Same logic applies to Referrer header, it tells a web server about the address of the webpage that linked to the resource being requested. Jsoup might need to pretend as a browser when it connects to certain website. Mark this as answer if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Use this site to identify the userAgent String for your browser. http://whatsmyuseragent.com/